# Prove that a group with exactly two proper nontrivial subgroups is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{p^3}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $G$ is a group and has exactly two nontrivial proper subgroups. Prove that $G$ is cyclic and $|G|=pq$ where p,q are distinct primes or $G$ is cyclic and $|G|=p^3$ where $p$ is a prime. Usually my tactic to show a group is cyclic is find an elements such that its order and order of the group are the same. But here I cannot do so because I have no informatio regarding order of elements. So I stuck. Can anyone help me?

Comment: By two you mean "exactly two"? And this refers to the number of nontrivial proper subgroups up to isomorphy?

Comment: @martin.koeberl It doubt it is "up to isomorphy" since $S_3$ has exactly two types of non-trivial proper subgroups.

Comment: ErickWong: That's not true. It has $4$ of them.

Comment: @azimut *Up to isomorphism* it has $\mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z_3$.

Comment: @ErickWong: 3 subgroups of order 2.

Comment: @azimut Notice they're talking about subgroups up to isomorphism.

Comment: @ErickWong: Oh yes, thanks for that.

Comment: @ErickWong: Thanks, I've missed that. I only read "two nontrivial proper subgroups" in the question.

Answer (score 8):

Hint: If there are only two subgroups $H,K \subset G$ then $H \cup K \neq G$ (why?). Now what can you say about an element $g \in G \setminus (H \cup K)$?

Comment: I don't see why $H\cup K\not=G$, could you explain this please?

Comment: @Amr Let $H,K$ be proper subgroups of $G$ and suppose that $H \cup K=G$. Pick $a \in G \setminus H$ and $b \in G \setminus K$ then $ab$ cannot be in $H$ because it would imply $a \in H$ similarly with $K$, so $ab \notin G$!

Comment: @Amr an alternate argument is $|H|, |K| \le \frac12 |G|$ and $|H \cap K| > 0$.

Comment: @JSchlather I see ! +1

Comment: @achille hui thanks for the alternate argument

Comment: @JSchlather: I'm not quite understand your purpose. Mind to explain it?

Comment: @Idonknow There are two proofs of the first step in the comments here so I'll assume it's not that. My suggestion is too look at the subgroup generated by an element $g \in G \setminus (H \cup K)$ the point is that $g \notin H$ and $g \notin K$ so what does that force the subgroup generated by $g$ to be? Once you have that the question is much simpler.

Comment: The subgroup generated by $g \in G\(H \cup K)$ will be a cyclic subgroup. I really have no idea.

Comment: @Idontknow The condition that $G$ has only two non-trivial subgroups $H, K$ implies $G$ has 4 subgroups, $\{e\}, H, K$ and $G$. The subgroup generated by $g \in G\setminus(H\cup K)$ cannot be $\{e\}, H$ nor $K$. This means $G$ is generated by $g$.

Answer (score 2):

**Case 1:** $|G|$ is not a $p-$group

**Proof:**  Let $p,q$ be two distinct divisors of $|G|$. Let $N_1,N_2$ be sylow p,q-subgroups respectively. Clearly, these two subgroups are distinct (because their orders are different).

Claim: $|N_1|=p$

Proof: Suppose not. $Z(N_1)$ can't be trivial, because $N_1$ is a p-subgroup). If $Z(N_1)\subseteq N_1$, then we get a contradiction because $N_1,N_2,Z(N_1)$ will be three distinct proper non-trivial subgroups. If $Z(N_1)|=N_1$, then $N_1$ is abelian, thus $N_1^p,N_1,N_2$ are distinct non-trivial proper subgroups.

Similarly, $|N_2|=q$. Since there are two proper non trivial subgroups, thus all conjugates of $N_1$ are equal to $N_1$. Hence, $N_1\lhd G$. Thus, $N_1N_2$ is another subgroup of $G$. Thus, $N_1N_2$ must be equal to $G$. Since $N_1\cap N_2=\{e\}$. Hence $|G|=|N_1N_2|=pq$

**Case 2:** $|G|=p^n$

**Proof:** By Sylow theorems, we know that $G$ has non trivial proper subgroups of order $p,p^2,...,p^{n-1}$. Thus, $n\leq 3$. $n\not=2$ ,because $G$ would either be $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_p\oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$. $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ has exactly one proper non-trivial subgroup. $\mathbb{Z_p}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_p$ has more than two non-trivial proper subgroups: $\langle(1,0)\rangle,\langle(1,1)\rangle,\langle(0,1)\rangle$. $n=0,1$ also lead to contradiction easily.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $G$ has exactly two nontrivial proper subgroups $H$ and $K$.

If $K$ has a proper nontrivial subgroup, then $H \leq K$. Thus $K$ has exactly one proper nontrivial subgroup, which means that $K$ is cyclic of order $p^2$. Hence $G$ must be a $p$-group of order $p^3$, and any element $x \not\in K$ will generate $G$.

If $H$ and $K$ do not have proper nontrivial subgroups, $H$ and $K$ will be cyclic of prime order. It is clear that $H$ and $K$ will be normal subgroups and that $G$ is cyclic of order $pq$.

You try can classify groups with exactly $n$ subgroups for small $n$. This is the case $n = 4$. You can try to do the case $n = 5$ by using the classification of groups with exactly $n = 1, 2, 3, 4$ subgroups. A starting point is to notice that if a group with $n$ subgroups contains a subgroup with $n-1$ subgroups, it will be cyclic.

After that you can think about how the number of subgroups affects the structure of groups. What is the largest $k$ such that every group with $\leq k$ subgroups is cyclic? Abelian?