# Prove a Galois group is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

Assume that $K$ is a finite normal extension of a field F with Galois group $G:=G(K/F)$. Assume that $K$ has exactly 2 distinct subfields $E_1$ and $E_2$ such that $F\subsetneq E_1$ and $E_2 \subsetneq K$, and assume $E_1$ and $E_2$ are both normal extensions of $F$. Prove $G$ is cyclic.

How am going to proceed? I think some sylow theorems might help. But I don't know how to start.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Think about the Galois-correspondence and see this question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322849/prove-that-a-group-with-exactly-two-proper-nontrivial-subgroups-is-isomorphic-to

Comment: I don't think we need both intermediate fields to be normal extensions of the base field. The result holds true without this condition.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure you can follow the following providing justifications:

First of all, what can be $\;n:=\;$ the extension's degree? Clearly $\;n\;$ can't be a prime number (why?), and it can't also be that $\;n\;$ has more than two proper non-trivial divisors. Thus, we either have $\;n=pq\;$ , for two different primes $\;p,q\;$ , or else $\;n=p^3\;$ for some prime $\;p\;$ .

In the first  first case $\;n=pq\;$: if the extension isn't cyclic then the Galois Group isn't even abelian and is thus the non-trivial semidirect product of two cyclic groups of order $\;p,\,q\;$. This case is possible only if $\;p<q\;$ and $\;p\,\mid\,(q-1)\;$ , say $\;q-1=kp\;$ , which would then  give us $\;q>1\;$ different subgroups of order $\;p\;$, a contradiction. Thus, $\;|G|=pq\;$ is **the** cyclic group of order $\;pq\;$ and indeed has one single subgroup of order $\;p,\,q\;$, and both subgroups correspond with normal extensions of $\;F\;$ since the whole extension is abelian and thus the subgps. are abelian, too.

If $\;[K:F]=|G=\text{Gal}\,(K/F)|=p^3\;$ , the group $\;G\;$ has two subgroups of orders $\;p,\,p^2\;$ . If $\;G\;$ isn't cyclic then it must have at least one subgroup more of at least one of the two orders $\;p,\,p^2\;$, which cannot be true by assumption...

Comment: Just one quick question. If I choose base field to be $\mathbb{Q} $ and the intermediate fields obtained by adjoining $\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3} $respectively and $K=\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, then Galois group is of order $4$ and yet only two intermediate fields $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{2}), \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{3}) $ are there. What am I missing here. Sorry if this question appears silly/trivial.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I think you may be forgetting the intermediate extension $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt6)\;$ ...And indeed: this extesion is **not** cyclic as its Galois group is $\;V\;$ , the Klein group.

Comment: Oh yes I did miss the $\sqrt{6}$. And yeah the group is $Z_2\times Z_2$ same as $V$.